# Nested block in css grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Blue Nested blocks are located inside div(`.card-container`) that described:

```css
body {
  margin: 0; }

header, footer, .slideshow, .card-container {
  background-color: gray;
  border: solid 1px black;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px; }

.card {
  border: solid 3px red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #4286f4;
  height: 450px; }

.card-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 340px);
  grid-auto-columns: 450px;
  grid-auto-rows: 450px;
  justify-content: center; }

header {
  grid-area: header; }

.slideshow {
  grid-area: slideshow; }

.card-container {
  grid-area: card-container; }

footer {
  grid-area: footer; }

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "slideshow" "card-container" "footer";
  grid-auto-rows: auto; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style-main-grid.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>grid-main</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-main-grid.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid">
      <header>
        Header
      </header>
      <div class="slideshow">
        Slideshow
      </div>
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
          <h2>.card</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <h2>.card</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <h2>.card</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <h2>.card</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <h2>.card</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <h2>.card</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <footer>
        Footer
      </footer>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Height of `.card-container` is constant and determinated the sum of the `.card`. How to make the height of `.card-container` adjusted for the current column of nested blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont just:

```
.card-container {
    grid-area: card-container;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: If using                                                                                                 `display: block; `                                                                                  `float: left;`                                                                                                                       then nested block line up one by one despite of width of the browser window

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `height` property from `.card`. You're forcing a certain size, so that's how big it will be.

Comment: I remove, but  it does not change anything. I want  the `.card`  have fix sizes   and this affected the property `grid-auto-rows: 450px`. If you removed it then height of `.card` is stretched filling the empty space of  `.card-container`

Comment: Can you create a diagram showing what you mean? My understanding is you just want each card to be 450px, with a container to fit them. My answer does just that.

Comment: I want to `.card-container` to be responsive and  `.card` have fix sizes [diagram](https://imgur.com/a/FYSo1)

Comment: Then change the width? Running your snippet, with the height property removed, does exactly what you're asking for. I don't see the issue.

Comment: I removed the height. It didn't help. The height of `.card-container` is constant  as before and equal to the sum of height all `.card` including grid-gap. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Why would it *not* be equal to the sum of all the card containers? That's even what your diagram shows.

Comment: well, my diagram shows how i want. In situation when cards are stacked one by one all good, but other situations have problem. Just Im a bad explaner

Comment: Show me what you mean. If you have two columns, the container will be half as tall. Your explanation of what you want is incredibly unclear.

Comment: This [diagram](https://imgur.com/a/gkLGy) shows what in reality. This [diagram](https://imgur.com/a/3Um2G) shows what i want to do.